# Highstock chart - Dates on same x axis and Crazy Tooltip

Tags: jsfiddle, highcharts

I am working with Highstock chart (from 'Point markers only' demo: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/markers-only) and I noticed the below issues:

a) I noticed that the corresponding tooltips are crazy

b) I noticed that the dates were plotted right over the left edge, almost hiding the tooltip symbols...

You may want to take a look at the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xfJhq/1/

I thank you for any clue you might have.

Comment: because you are having all your y points an the same x-axis point  ? are you doing this on  purpose

Comment: where do you have this `x: 1324512000000,` data source ?

Comment: @MinaGabriel:  Why the answer down voted ? If its wrong.Then please provide correct answer or justification.

Comment: @MinaGabriel, yes this is on purpose. Those dates did happened on the same day, however with different values. Also, x: 132451200000 is a valid date coming from my system.

Answer (score 1):

since you mentioned you have more data to add here is what i would do :

*NOTICE* the tool tip reads one point per series hover so it return the nearest point to the mouse cursor

```
     tooltip: {
            allowHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                console.log(this.points) ; 

            }
        },
```

the following object  was the nearest point  :

```
return [
        key: "SALKTU - LEVEL ZERO"
        percentage: undefined
        point: xa
        series: c
        total: undefined
        x: 1324512000000
        y: 91
        __proto__: Object ]
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/xfJhq/3/)

to solve this you need more than one `yAxis`

So i would do it this way

```
         yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height:100,
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: 200,
            height: 100,
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        } , {
        title: {
                text: 'max'
            },
            top: 320,
            height: 100,
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2

        } ,{
        title: {
                text: 'min'
            },
            top: 450,
            height: 100,
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2

        } ,
               ],

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'RBWQCR - LEVEL ONE',
            data :[[1324512000000 ,81]]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'JPXZTO - LEVEL EIGHT',

            yAxis: 1,
            data:[[1324512000000 ,81]]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'CXRCTO - LEVEL THREE',

            yAxis: 2,
            data: [[1324512000000 ,81]]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'FLOPAP - LEVEL FOUR',

            yAxis:3,
            data :[[1324512000000 ,81]]
        }]
```

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/tgx2w/) when you pass all your data your chart will looks better

if you don't like having each one in a separate series look at the following [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/#save) it is a little complicated but worth to try

Comment: This is not exactly what I want, however your effort made me realize that maybe I should use another type of chart to my data... Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

As you have data for only one particular date.

Adding `minPadding` to your x axis will work.

Check updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xfJhq/2/

Note: I know that `minPadding` does not work on zoom and I have reported the same [question](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=18261) to Highstock forums.

Comment: @MinaGabriel: Can you please answer to my comment ?

Comment: @HardikMishra, this looks nice, yet did not completely work. If I change the date range, the issue appears again... Nice try! Any other idea?

Comment: @hamiltonjose: What is the need to change the date range ? When you have only one date.

Comment: @HardikMishra, in fact this is only a sample. I have several other dates and values to be ploted....

Comment: @hamiltonjose: Check this http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=18261. I have reported the same.